# Cannot resolve symbol from gradle plugin in build.gradle, even though it compiles correctly. (gradle-idea-ext-plugin)

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

I recently added the `org.jetbrains.gradle.plugin.idea-ext` plugin to my Gradle project.

```groovy
plugins {
    id "org.owasp.dependencycheck" version "6.1.6"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm"  version "1.4.32" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring" version "1.4.32" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.gradle.plugin.idea-ext" version "1.0"
    id "com.avast.gradle.docker-compose" version "0.14.3"
}


import static org.jetbrains.gradle.ext.ActionDelegationConfig.TestRunner.PLATFORM

idea.project.settings {
    delegateActions {
        delegateBuildRunToGradle = true // Delegate Run/Build to Gradle
        testRunner = PLATFORM    // Test execution: PLATFORM, GRADLE or CHOOSE_PER_TEST
    }
}
```

However, I get a `Cannot resolve symbol 'ActionDelegationConfig'` error in the IDE, even though it compiles correctly. What's weirder is that the auto complete does find the symbols, but the editor still highlights the line as an error. Any ideas?

I have tried:

- Invalidating all caches and restarting the IDE
- `git clean -fdx`
- Deleting all of `$HOME/.gradle`
- Installing the groovysdk.
- Older versions of the plugin.

My IDE:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-211.7142.45, built on April 30, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+9-b1341.41 x86_64
VM: Dynamic Code Evolution 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 10.15.7
Registry: localHistory.daysToKeep=30, ide.balloon.shadow.size=0, scala.erase.compiler.process.jdk.once=false
Kotlin: 211-1.5.0-release-759-IJ6693.72
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an issue with IDE resolving the plugin's Groovy DSK. Created the bug for it: [IDEA-269820](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-269820).